# Does React make sure an element id stays unique?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Lets stay we have two components: `ItemForm` and `Inpunt` . I am passing `label` and `id` props to `Input`, :

```
const ItemForm = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <Input
        label= "Name:"
        input={{
          id: "brandName",
          type: "text"
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

And here we have the `Input` component:

```
const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={props.input.id}>{props.label}</label>
      <input {...props.input} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**My question is:** when we use these components multiple times in a project, how does the id prop remains unique, even when we are explicitly saying that `id = "brandName"` ? (similar to writing plain html when we can't have more than one instance of an id.)

PS : It works when I use these components, but I want to know WHY and HOW it works under the hood!

Comment: no thats why they introduced `useId()` hook - https://react.dev/reference/react/useId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't (just use `<Input>` twice in a row with the same id).

A possible solution is to append a unique identifier to the id to make sure it is unique:

```js
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function getId(id) {
  return `${id}_${nanoid()}`;
}

const Input = ({ input, label }) => {
  const id = getId(input.id);
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input {...input} id={id} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I used [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) for this example.

Comment: I see where my mistake is. Using the ItemForm itself multiple times will not cause a problem since it is holding only ONE instance of the Input module. However, using the Input component itself multiple times will cause an error.